# Storing array of objects in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've get a problem with storing an array of normal js objects in parse.com.
Is it even possible?

```
var ObjectClass = new Parse.Object.extend("ObjectClass");
var object  = new ObjectClass();
object.set("name", [{'a': 'b'}]);
object.save() - > Error 121


{"code":121,"error":"Nested keys should not contain the '$' or '.' characters."}
```

Comment: Try replacing single quotes to double quotes in your name value: `object.set("name", [{"a": "b"}]);`

Comment: It does not work ;-(

Answer (score -1):

First things first, I believe your first line should say:

```
var ObjectClass = Parse.Object.extend("ObjectClass");
```

Without the "new" keyword, unless you're building the schema as you go, which *should be* fine (thanks to MongoDB), although I'm not certain.

After that, what you're doing should work if you switch your quotes from single-quotes ('') to double-quotes ("").

Comment: In JavaScript, single and double quotes are equivalent.